# Pass commands to Chrome via CLI or Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, pdf, printing

I want to open a PDF URL, print it, and close the window. I've tried doing this through Selenium, but the page is behind a login auth, which is retained in normal Chrome, but seems impossible to get past when using chromedriver. My Python script can open the page via `os.system(f"open '/Applications/Google Chrome.app' -u '{url}'")`, so all I need to do is effectively cmd-P, enter, cmd-W (macOS). Can it be done?

Comment: If you want to simulate actual keyboard input, you can use a library like pyautogui.

Comment: it is possible to do this with `selenium` or with `pyautogui`...

Comment: Thanks, will try pyautogui. Selenium failed the login, even when I let it open the page and wait for me to type login info directly including Captcha info, login failed or was blocked. I'm assuming it's detecting the use of chromedriver or Selenium or something.

Comment: ...pyautogui worked(!), though it seems that Chrome ate and ignored the cmd-P at the beginning. It would open the window from the os.system call, then close it, so I knew Chrome was getting the cmd-W. Added delays, but that didn't seem to make any difference. Added an 'enter' at the beginning, and the print dialog worked too. Ah well, happy to have something that works, even if it's a bit shaggy.